# sDNA - sum of traffic along shortest path

Tags: shortest-path, sdna

I am trying to get a measure or proxy of the estimated aadt encountered along the shortest path. One way would be to compute shortest paths between origins (around 280) and destinations (one) via skim matrix with a) no aadt penalty and b) with an aadt penalty, and use the difference between the mean distances. That tells me to some extent how far the way to the destination might be subject to either a detour or, if no detour is feasible, the length penalty due to aadt. But - is there any way to output the sum of aadt encountered along the shortest path in sDNA - essentially the value used to derive the variable trafficfac?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sDNA Geodesics to output all the shortest paths of interest, then use your GIS's functionality to join them to the network and sum all the aadt values (weighted by length I imagine). This will work fine for your 280 geodesics.

Comment: Of course! I was thinking too complicated here. 
Thank you!